# Finding $x$ for which $x + x^6 + 1/3 (x^3 + x^4) + 1/2 (x^2 + x^5) \geq -\log(1-x)$ holds

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

Assume $0 < x < 1$, I'm looking for the range in which the following holds:

$$ x + x^6 + \frac{1}{3} (x^3 + x^4) + \frac{1}{2} (x^2 + x^5) \geq -\log(1-x) $$

Using Wolfram Mathematica, it seems like $x \in (0, 0.958)$.

I'm not really sure how problems like this are typically addressed. Can we arrive to an answer like this analytically, or is this typically solved numerically?

Comment: Typically you have to do it numerically.  Most problems don't have closed form solutions.  I should think you can prove analytically that the answer is of the form $(0,c)$, but you'll have to compute $c$ numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tedious but, at least, partly doable with algebra.

Consider the function
$$f(x)=x + x^6 + \frac{1}{3} (x^3 + x^4) + \frac{1}{2} (x^2 + x^5) +\log(1-x)$$ which rewrite
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{6} x (x+1) \left(6 x^4-3 x^3+5 x^2-3 x+6\right)+\log (1-x)$$ Compute its derivative and use common denominator to get
$$f'(x)=-\frac {x^2}{6(1-x)}(36 x^3-21 x^2-7 x-2)$$ The cubic equation shows only one real root since $\Delta=-333567$.

Using the hyperbolic method, this root is
$$x_*=\frac{1}{36} \left(7+2 \sqrt{133} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2521}{133 \sqrt{133}}\right)\right)\right)\sim 0.877198$$  At this point, we have (numerically)
$$f(x_*)=0.302407 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x_*)=-35.9665$$ So, $x_*$ correspond to a maximum point and the solution of $f(x)=0$ is somewhere between $x_*$ and $1$.

Now, to polish the solution, use Newton method with, say, $x_0=\frac 12(x_*+1)$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.938599 \\
 1 & 0.966853 \\
 2 & 0.959375 \\
 3 & 0.957826 \\
 4 & 0.957774
\end{array}
\right)$$